# Show message to one player issue in multi-player game

Tags: c#, unity, multiplayer, smartfox

I Needed to show message to only one person of the multi player game,i am using smartfoxserver to developed a board based game and in this game how to differentiate 2 players in unity c#,and also how to display any messages to single person in unity c#, i am new from unity so please help me.

Comment: This is kind of a big topic.  I assume your core question is about how to send messages via SmartFox to a single player?  What have you tried and what problems specifically have you run into?

Comment: yes i needed as u told same & i am also explain the situation of game. I have done a Board based Game ,In this Game same Like as a Tic tac Toe ,in this have 2 Players , so i.e assuming player 1 & player 2.so first turn is Player 1 turn , in this time player 2 trying click on board so we have show one msg i.e this not ur turn.this is i needed.-@Sean Middleditch.

Comment: @user2914179 this... is almost like asking how to make your whole game...

Answer (score 0):

I am using SmartFoxServer with Java and JavaScript so I do not really know if this is going to work for you.
You should create an EventListener for "click". So like you said, when player 1 is playing and player 2 is click on the board you should send from client 2 (player 2 ) a message to the server with a Command ( for example "CLICK_BOARD" ). Than you create a handle request function on your server to get the request you allready send form the client. In this Function you can use  check for the command. If you get the command "CLICK_BOARD" than you send back to the client another COMMAND with the name "WRONG_TURN". On client side when you get this COMMAND you event listener will trigger a function. This function should show the message.

I hope you undestand my ideas.